# Using scopes in Rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, sqlite

I am trying to define a scope in my Account model but it is not working.  Here is my code:

```
class Account < ActiveRecord::Base

    has_many :organizations

    scope :primary, joins(:organizations).where('organizations.primary = ?', true)

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :organizations
end

class Organization < ActiveRecord::Base

    belongs_to :account

    has_many :locations

    accepts_nested_attributes_for :locations
end
```

From the console, I tried the following command:

```
Account.primary.first
```

But I get the following error:

```
ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: SQLLite3::SQLException: near "primary":
syntax error: SELECT "accounts".* FROM "accounts" INNER JOIN "organizations" ON
"organizations"."account_id" = "accounts"."id" WHERE (organizations.primary = 't')
LIMIT 1
```

I think the name 'primary' might be causing the problem.  When I renamed the scope to "important" and tried that I get:

```
NoMethodError: undefined method 'important' for #<Class:0x1f4a900>
```

If anyone can help I would very much appreciate it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think your problem is that you have a *column* named "primary" and that's a [reserved word](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_keywords.html). Try quoting it:

```
scope :primary, joins(:organizations).where('organizations."primary" = ?', true)
```

This exception:

> SQLLite3::SQLException: near "primary":

is coming from SQLite, not from ActiveRecord or Rails.

Comment: No, no luck with the quotes.  Any other ideas?  Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Corey: Same exception or a new one?

Comment: Same exception.  But I changed the 'primary' column to 'primary_organization' and it works.  Thank you!